# Video sequence editor won't place media files at the playhead position when they're dragged and dropped

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Since Blender 3.2.0 when a media file is dragged and dropped from the OS's file manager (I'm on Linux, so it's Gnome) to the Blender's video sequencer, it won't be positioned where the playhead currently is, instead it's placed at the very first frame. This problem is absent when the file is chosen from Blender's add menu (file browser). Any suggestions on how to fix this problem, or how it can be addressed to the devs?

Comment: It's not going to the first frame, it's just going to the last frame it remembers you using for that operator. Blender has a [built-in file browser](https://imgur.com/a/QsLvRj2) in the default Video Editing layout, why not just use that?

Comment: It goes to the frame 1 of the track 1 every time. I'm dealing with this issue on a daily basis. If the first track is occupied with other strip, a dragged and dropped file goes either before or right after it (shuffle mode). It doesn't remember position of the playhead: if media file was added through build-in file browser, drag and drop right after that again positions new strip to the first frame of the track #1. Build-in file browser doesn't support audio preview, it's impossible for me to chose correct sfx file out of hundreds of others with similar names without hearing it first.

Comment: Once again: everything was working just fine prior to the Blender 3.2.0 release.